# Do cosmologists see length contraction in the stars?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology

Wouldn't we be able to see length contraction in objects, like stars, that we can see and are moving at relativistic speeds?

Comment: Actually, what you would "see" for *any* object (not merely stars) due to length contraction is not merely contraction, but [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle yes. But there are at least two reason that we don't observe this:

##### **Stars are slow**

First of all, stars don't move at relativistic velocities. Typical velocities of stars in a galaxy is of the order of $100$s of $\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. In rare cases, such as if one star of a binary goes supernova and gives the other star a kick, you can have "hypervelocity stars" that reach $\sim\!\!1000\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$.

Galaxies themselves move with similar velocities. In the case of two galaxies merging, you can also have substantially larger velocities (of $1000$s of $\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$), but this is still nowhere near relativistic velocities.

##### **Stars are small**

Second, stars are very far away compared to their sizes, so only the nearest ones ($\lesssim1000$ lightyears) are actually resolved, and since their angular sizes are measured in *milli*arcseconds, measuring a difference in the diameter of the same star in two directions would be extremely difficult. Moreover, since velocities of nearby stars tend to move in more or less the direction as we do, their velocities relative to are more like 10s of $\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$.

##### **Observed length contraction**

So, how do we know length contraction is a real thing? Measuring it directly is not really possible, but several experiments show the effect anyway. For instance, muons created high above Earth's surface decay so fast that they wouldn't be able to reach the surface. Yet we detect them, and the reason is that in their reference frame, the trip to the surface is much shorter than in our reference frame, so they have the time to get down after all. Another example is protons in accelerators which are flattened due to length contraction. This cannot be seen directly, but can be inferred from the way they scatter.

##### **Length contraction in an expanding Universe**

EDIT: I understand now that you were thinking of length contraction of galaxies carried away from us because of the expansion of the Universe. This is actually a great question, which at the moment doesn't seem to have a good answer, but according to astrophysicist Tamara Davis, the simple answer is that the galaxies' recession velocities are not "peculiar" velocities (i.e. motion *through* space), and therefore we don’t see length contraction. I may be able to update this answer in some months.

Comment: Aren't there systems a long distance away that are moving an appreciable % the speed of light in relation to us?

Comment: @joshperry  Indeed there are, but they are so far away that length measurement of their constituents is not possible.

Comment: @joshperry: Ah okay, I see. Yes, galaxies recede at relativistic velocities and even super-luminal velocities due to the expansion of the Universe. Although "relativistic velocities" is not really how to think of it, as this is not SR, but GR. I'll edit my answer to include this, but don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: For stars, or any spherical object, there is also the issue of the Terrell-Penrose effect. Even if we could resolve their extent by optical observations, their observed shape would still be spherical: for spherical objects optical signal delay happens to compensate exactly for length contraction. Galaxies, otoh, would be another matter, depending on orientation.

Comment: @joshperry: Sorry for the delay. It turned out to be a rather complex question. I discussed it with a friend (Tamara Davis) who knows more about this stuff than I do. Right now she can't give a better answer than "recession velocities are not peculiar velocities, and therefore we don’t see length contraction", but in a while she might have a better answer.

Comment: Isn't for the galaxies the space itself sort of stretching at a velocity greater than c . But that doesn't violate Relativity because it's the space that stretching faster than c . So do we or should we observe the length contraction of galaxies in that case

Comment: @Shashaank: I guess that's the point. Space expand at arbitrarily high velocities, but nothing moves _through_ space faster than c. But if you observe a galaxy at a distance of, say, 14 billion lightyears, it _does_ recede from you at almost the speed of light, and you might expect that velocity to cause it to length contract. But apparently it doesn't.

Comment: @pela I have read certain galaxies are receding faster than c . I read it when I was understanding the 92 light years length of the universe

Comment: @Shashaank: Yes, the recession velocity of a galaxy is simply proportional to its distance from us, and since you can have arbitrarily large distances, you can have arbitrarily large velocities. Minor correction to your last comment. It's _billion_ light years, as I'm sure you meant, and that number is referring to the diameter (as opposed to radius).

Comment: @pela Yes 92 Billion Light years as opposed to 13.8 billion light years. If the expansion of space can be at a greater pace than c ( this also not violates Relativity ) then there can't be any length contraction .Not because we cannot observe it but because it can't happen by Relativity , I guess. Just a beginner at General Relativity , I can only guess right now.

Comment: @Shashaank: I'm not sure it's that easy. For instance, there _is_ time dilation for a galaxy at arbitrarily large redshift $z$ by a factor $(1+z)$.

Comment: @pela Ok Thanku. Will search for it.  Learn it when it calls. Thanku

Comment: @pela I appreciate the response and taking the time to reach out to your colleague. I look forward to any other info you might be able to add in the future.

Comment: What about now where a star has been found orbiting a black hole at 0.08c? https://www.space.com/fastest-star-ever-moves-8-percent-light-speed.html

Comment: @DKNguyen Quite amazing! But the star will still only be contracted by 0.3%, and it is far beyond the distance at which we can measure its size directly.